# difference between Editor Fold and Region comments in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android studio there is two option for code folding. one is Editor fold tag (`<editor-fold desc="Description">`) and one is region comment (`//region Description`).

I used both for code folding, but never understand what is a different between both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is in style. `<editor-fold..>` provides NetBeans folding style and `region..endregion` provides VisualStudio folding style.

**Note:**

You can only choose one of the style for a particular file. No mixing should be done.